# UIPopoverController and UITapGestureRecognizer not working in ViewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller, xcode-storyboard

When I add a `UIPopoverController` in the `ViewDidLoad` method, it displays an empty popover view. The same thing happens when I add a `UITapGestureRecognizer`; it doesn't trigger the attached method. If I put the code in my `ViewDidAppear` it does work, but in some cases `ViewDidAppear` is never called, depending on where in my storyboard the view is loaded.

Here's my code:

```
UIViewController* popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UIView *popoverView = [[UIView alloc] init];
popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
popoverContent.view = popoverView;

pickerPopup = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];
pickerPopup.delegate = (id)self;

[pickerPopup setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 240) animated:NO];
```

And the `UITapGestureRecognizer`:

```
tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(openPicker:)];
[_form_from addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it for now using a delay in the `ViewDidLoad` method like so

```
[self performSelector:@selector(custom_init) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
```

Still don't get why the `UITapGestureRecognizer` doesn't trigger. It does work if I attach it to the view, but not if I attach it to a textfield in a static cell.